# How to make Variable within foreach loop exist?

Tags: c#, string, variables, foreach

I apologize if this sounds like a ignorant question but I am quite new to C#. I am one error away from getting my program to work:

"the name 'filesInfo' does not exist in the current context"

I am trying to get this variable to exist and attempted at solving this by declaring it outside the foreach loop, but to no avail.

Here is my current script:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string src = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderA";
    public static string dst = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderB";
    public static string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.txt");

    public void Move_Modified_Files()
    {
        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
            FileInfo filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        }

        try
        {
            if (filesInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
            {
                File.Move(src, dst);
                Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass cls = new MyClass();
        cls.Move_Modified_Files();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the ' }' after 'new FileInfo(fileName);' and put the '}' to the end of the 'Move_Modified_Files' method.

Comment: You declared it inside that loop which creates a block level scope (context), so that is where it exists (only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring `filesInfo` within the `foreach` loop. As such, its scope is restricted to that loop. If you want to use it elsewhere, you have to move it to the corresponding scope:

```
FileInfo filesInfo;

foreach (string s in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
    filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
}

try
{
    if (filesInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
    {
        File.Move(src, dst);
        Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
}
```

That being said, you are currently overriding `filesInfo` on every iteration of the loop. I imagine that you wanted to check `filesInfo` for every value of `s`, so what you actually wanted to do is this:

```
foreach (string s in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
    FileInfo filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    try
    {
        if (filesInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
            File.Move(src, dst);
            Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see! What I should have done was use the try/catch inside the foreach loop before the variable disappears. Thank you for clarifying. All other answers were great but you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void Move_Modified_Files()
{
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
        FileInfo filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        try
        {
            if (filesInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
            {
                File.Move(src, dst);
                Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
FileInfo filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
```

inside the first loop. When this context ends  with the `}` the variable will disappear.

My guess is that you wanted to do this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string src = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderA";
    public static string dst = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderB";
    public static string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.txt");

    public void Move_Modified_Files()
    {
        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            // These values will exist until their enclosing context is closed
            // The context starts with the most recent opening bracket {
            // So these values, will exist until this loop iterates to the next value
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
            FileInfo filesInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

            // Attempt to use the currently selected fileinfo
            try
            {
                if (filesInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
                {
                    File.Move(src, dst);
                    Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            }

            // The next } bracket below is the one that closes the context mentioned earlier
            // When it closes, all values declared in this sub-context will no longer exist.
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass cls = new MyClass();
        cls.Move_Modified_Files();
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted in the OP "the name 'filesInfo' does not exist in the current context", so 'string fileName' is not the problem. You probably copied the wrong line.

Comment: ah, right, copied wrong line.. thanks!